# how does the new keyword in hql work?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hql

I found this example in jboss's documentation.

```
select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
from DomesticCat as mother
    join mother.mate as mate
    left join mother.kittens as offspr
```

Where does the `Family` class come from. Do I need to import somewhere, or to use its fully qualified class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Family` is a plain POJO with the appropriate constructor which either needs to be declared or fully qualified.

Comment: @flybywire As entity (annotated or mapped)

Answer (score 2):

`Family` must be a Java object that has an appropriate constructor. The import is optional if the object is a normal mapped entity (either using using annotations or in a hibernate mapping XML).

Answer (score 1):

The import is optional, if it is found for another reason. :-)

Yes, it needs to exist. It is a class that is not an entity, you create it to handle in a intelligible way the three columns. It needs a constructor appropriate for the call.

Basically, it is like if you did:

- a query that returns List (with the three columns)
- loop on the list, creates a Family object holding the columns, and return the list of these results

Comment: if the import is optional and the class is not an entity, how will Hibernate find it? In which packages will it look for it?

Comment: @Flybywire True, it has to be found in some way :-). It is found if declared an an entity, if in a default package for Hibernate, or if imported. I was not very clear in my answer, because it is true that Entities are always in the first case. :-)