# SpringBoot+Hibernate+Restful : format response

Tags: hibernate, rest, api, spring-boot

I am newbie with Hibernate and trying to create an API which will return current position. 
So in DaoImpl I write a query

```
public List<Location> getCurrentLocation() {

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select l.employee.id, max(l.locationTime) as currentTime, l.longtitude , l.latitude,l.date from Location l group by l.employee.id").list();
}
```

In controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "currentLocation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Location>> getCurrentLocation() {
        List<Location> location;
        try {
            location = locationService.getCurrentLocation();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Location>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Location>>(location, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and when I call that API I receive this response

`[[11,"07:30:00",106.634756,10.826307,"2017-11-23"],[15,"07:00:00",106.632142,10.826456,"2017-11-24"]]`
I just want to ask why I can't get the attribute name. I still don't get it.
Is there any one can explain this, and How can I get the attribute name 
for example `['employeename':11,'time':"07:30:00",'longtitude':106.634756,'latitude':10.826307,'workday':"2017-11-23"]`
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply: you use projections like `l.employee.id`.

For this query

`select loc from Location loc`

or `from Location` (the same short version)

Hibernate returns `List<Location>`, but when you begin to use projections, Hibernate returns `List<Object[]>`. That list you have as a response.

`list()` returns a simply `List` (not generic), so you have an unchecked conversion

`List<Object[]> -> List<Location>`

**What can you do**

1. Convert query result to a `Map` using transformer and return that `Map` as a result from the endpoint.
2. Add class `LocationDto` and map result to the list of `DTO` using other transformer.
3. Use a `some.package.LocaitionDto` constructor directly in the query (don't forget a package, please) ([how does the new keyword in hql work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145693/how-does-the-new-keyword-in-hql-work)).

Don't forget to add alias to each projection, please.

[Spring Hibernate get selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811595/spring-hibernate-get-selected-columns/35813216)

[java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to className](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883895/java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-classname/36883968)

[How to transform a flat result set using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361256/how-to-transform-a-flat-result-set-using-hibernate/36361630)