# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.infotech.model.Transaction(class)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Here is my code given below I'm not able to fetch records from my Transaction table as it displays error--java.lang.ClassCastException Ljava.lang.Object cannot be cast to com.infotech.model.Transaction

Help me out where is the issue 
Note- Transaction is my class

```
 ArrayList<Transaction> arr1 = null;
    Transaction tt1=null;

    try{

            SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
            session= sessionfactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
    int uid = search.getUser_id();
    Query query1=session.createQuery("select A_no, date, type, B_id from Transaction t where t.user_id=:uid");
            query1.setInteger("uid", uid);



            List<Transaction> list=query1.list();

             Iterator<Transaction> itr1=list.iterator();
                arr1=new ArrayList<Transaction>();


                while(itr1.hasNext())
                {
                     tt1=itr1.next();
                     arr1.add(tt1);
                    System.out.println(tt1.getA_no()+"\t"+tt1.getB_id());
                }

           }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();} 


            ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView("form-search","data",tt);
            m.addObject("copy", arr1);
```

Comment: try this query1.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Transaction.class)).list(); instead of this query1.list().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you use projections Hibernate returns `List<Object[]>` (not `List<Transaction>`).

The simplest thing is to change the HQL query, just to check that everything works

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("from Transaction t where t.user_id=:uid");
```

Please, read this if you want to use projections

[SpringBoot+Hibernate+Restful : format response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777323/springboothibernaterestful-format-response/47783102#47783102)

Answer (score 0):

It must be this line:

```
List<Transaction> list=query1.list();
```

You should change it to `List<Transaction> list= (List<Transaction>)(List<?>) query1.list();`

Java requires **explicit type casting** from derived types to base types.